# What is wrong with this angular code?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-interpolate

This is the code that I am using to get images:

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}{{product.image}}" class="product-image">
```

But it wont fetch the image.

it only gets the file path but not the product image name.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax should be

```
<img ng-src="{{url + product.image}}" class="product-image">
```

Comment: I still get the same file path

Comment: @RyanByrne could you update your question with what error you are getting & what your are expecting..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the "/" with url/image try with src instead of ng-src

```
<img src="{{url}}/{{product.image}}" class="product-image">
```

Comment: I tried this but the path I get now is: mydomain.com/xxx/cms/api/uploads/&quot;

Answer (score 0):

Do you tryed to show in console the result of the variables url and product.image?

```
console.log(url + product.image);
```

The value is correct?